# xamarin System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot convert "VerticalGrid, 2" into Xamarin.Forms.IItemsLayout'

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I'm getting the error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot convert "VerticalGrid, 2" into Xamarin.Forms.IItemsLayout'` during InitalizeComponent() of my ContentPage containing a CollectionsView.

The code works properly on UWP, and the error occurs when running on Android. Being new to xamarin.forms, I'm not really sure what to start looking for.

EDIT: it works if I choose "VerticalList".

Here's a bit of my xaml:

```
<ContentPage ... >

  <StackLayout>
    <CollectionView
      x:Name="DetailGrid"
      ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2" >

      <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="Crimson">
            <Image Source= "{Binding Path}" WidthRequest="300"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" TextColor ="Bisque" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
          </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And here's some code-behind:

```
namespace varlist
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class CollectionPage : ContentPage
  {
    public ObservableCollection<NodeData> nodes = new ObservableCollection<NodeData>();

    public CollectionPage ()
    {
      InitializeComponent ();

      nodes.Add (new ImageData { FileName = "image_chair_pk.jpg" });
      ...
      DetailGrid.ItemsSource = nodes;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are TAGGING xamarin.forms and collectionView. You could be way more clear by tagging VERTICALGRID

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Forms package version?

Comment: Xamarin   16.8.000.255 (d16-8@d002176)     -------
Xamarin Designer   16.8.0.507 (remotes/origin/d16-8@e87b24884)  -------
Xamarin Templates   16.8.112 (86385a3)     -----
Xamarin.Android SDK   11.1.0.17 (d16-8/c0e2b8e)     -------
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error with you when I use a `Xamarin.forms version 4.5.0.725`.

After I update my Xamarin.forms to the latest version `4.8.0.1687`, everything works well.

Please update your Xamarin.forms version to fix this problem:

[image]

Comment: Ah, maybe they fixed it ! I'll give it a try. Thanks. Interesting: I actually checked for new versions a little while ago and VS didn't report anything out of date.

Comment: Yes, I just test and the latest version works. Can you please accept the answer if it works so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Still not working for me on Android. I have the same versions that you show in your screenshot. I do have some build warnings, one in particular that I'm concerned about:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from 4.8.0.1687 to 4.8.0.1560. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 varlist.uwp -> varlist -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1687) 
 varlist.uwp -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1560)

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of that. I suspect it's relevant.

Comment: Sorry to not understand, but what do you mean by "update?". I've rebuilt and the warnings don't go away. Is there someplace versioning is specified that can override the overall installation ?

Comment: There is another similar warning for NETCore.Platforms.

Comment: There is a version conflict between your nuget packages. Update means you should update your varlist.uwp to a higher version.

Comment: Ok, it appears that one has to update each project separately. Updating nuget from the VS menubar doesn't seem to update the projects. Did that, and yes ! VerticalGrid works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. This appears to be a framework bug.

According to [Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout) the syntax I used should work - and it does work for UWP.

They also show an alternate declaration to specify ItemsLayout:

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
  <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

And, this syntax works on Android.

I filed a bug on github:[[Bug] CollectionView with ItemsLayout=VerticalGrid crashes on Android #12920](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12920)

Answer (score -1):

You can omit this property if you wish it vertical, the default is set to `VerticalList`. If you want your `collectionView` to be Horizontal, just use `HorizontalList`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout